# Making query from a list with varying amount of values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have for example the following lists:

```
list1 = ['blue', 'red']
list2 = ['green', 'yellow', 'black']
```

How could i create a query searching for all values (using postgresql).

This will work fine but it's hardcoded for only two values and therefore not handling the varying amount of values of the lists.

```
entry.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('colors')).filter(search=SearchQuery('blue') | SearchQuery('red'))
```

I tried the following to create a 'search_query' string and place it in my query:

```
for c in color:
   search_string += "SearchQuery('" + c +"') | "

search_string = search_string[:-3]
```

This will result in the following search_strings

```
SearchQuery('blue') | SearchQuery('red')
SearchQuery('green') | SearchQuery('yellow') | SearchQuery('black')
```

If i now put this string in my query, it will not work.

```
entry.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('colors')).filter(search=search_string)
```

I appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Link to django postgres search documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about postgreSQL but:

```
# Can run this query with SQL (i think django query auto convert for each type of DataBase???)
res = Models.Objects.filter(color__in = list1)
more_res = Models.Objects.filter( Q(color__in = list1) | Q(color__in = list2))
```

Django query basic (i don't know if it work for you???)

Answer (score 1):

Your `search_string` is not working because it is, well, a string.

You can use `eval` to make it work. Try this:

```
entry.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('colors')).filter(search=eval(search_string))
```

It is not the best way though. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)